# Passing UTM in the code?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Is there a way to add additional code in the HTML to pass the UTM parameters to Google Analytics? Usually you would pass the parameters in the URL:

domain.com/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=promotions&utm_campaign=Marketing%20Channel%20Name

Instead I am wondering if this info can be passed in the HTML instead of in the URL like in my above example.

I *thought* I remember reading this somewhere but maybe I am wrong...I can't find a link explaining anything on it.

Anyone?

Comment: I don't know why this question was closed except to assume the mod who closed it doesn't understand anything about Google Analytics.

Comment: Anyways, if you are using old style tracking (`ga.js`), there is no way to do this. You can [override what url params to look for](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiCampaignTracking) but you can't directly set them. If you are using the new Universal Analytics (`analytics.js`), then you [can set campaign vars directly](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#trafficsources)

Comment: To add to @CrayonViolent's answer - you can do it in ga.js by using the 2nd param in _trackPageview and append your values with the correct url params.

Comment: Great..thanks guys. Yeah I figured the moderator didn't understand so I clarified. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone closed this for no apparent reason. The answer to my question was yes...you can pass the UTM in the HTML in both the old (ga.js) and the new universal analytics (analytics.js).

Like Crayon Violent mentioned that it can be done with analytics.js while MisterPhilip followed up with a correction. You can do it with both old and new Google Analytics.

For the Universal Analytics you can set the vars up directly:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#trafficsources

And in the old GA you use the 2nd parameter in _trackPageview.

Thanks to whoever reopened this ticket.